# How to access Jade Main Container via internet?

Tags: java, agents-jade

I am working on an Agent based application and i want to access agents running on a container in a machine. I am using jadeGateWay to connect to Main container. It is working in localhost but when i run the jadeGateWay on a server it doesn't connect eventhough correct IP address of the jade main container are given. Can anybody suggest me a work around? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you, for the beginning, that you try to make the connection using jadegateway in the same machine, if works, try to do the same in other machine, as you want. If do not works, you could send more information about the problem.

And if you did not read yet, it's interesting read the **jadegateway api** on: http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/wrapper/gateway/JadeGateway.html.